# How to normalize two hierarchy levels of many to one relation while one of the relations is optional?

Tags: sql

Say there are 3 tables:

```
Table A           

| id      |
+---------+
| integer |

Table B

| id      | a_id                             | 
+---------+----------------------------------+
| integer | integer NOT NULL REFERENCES A(id)|

Table C

| id      | a_id                              | b_id                     |
+---------+-----------------------------------+--------------------------+
| integer | integer NOT NULL REFERENCES A(id) | integer REFERENCES B(id) |
```

`b_id` in `Table C` should only reference a row in `Table B` where `c.a_id = b.a_id`

What is the appropriate way to design that relation and keep the tables normalized?

Reading references are also welcome, I couldn't figure what to look for.

Context graphic example:

```
Folder_
       |_File 
       |_File 
       |_SubFolder_
       |           |_File
       |_SubFolder_
       |           |_File
       |           |_File
       |           |_File
       |_SubFolder
```

In my case `SubFolder` is not a `Folder` it's even represented more like a tag in the system. It's existence only is for file grouping without any other features.

Comment: Can you also describe what data these three tables are supposed to be representing?  I feel that there might be a design smell with Table C, but I can't say anything very concrete without knowing more about your data.

Comment: I've edited the question with context example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the 3 tables are necessary (because of other fields not mentioned here for simplicity), you can define a foreign key using multiple fields:

```
ALTER TABLE C
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_C_TO_B
   FOREIGN KEY(a_id, b_id)
   REFERENCES B(a_id,id)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would work with *identifying relationships*.

B is defined as being a child of a - I would therefore identify it by the foreign key to a parent and just a sequence starting at 1.

C is defined as being a child of b - so I would identify it by the foreign key to B - that's A's primary key plus B's sequence - and yet another sequence for C.

So:

```
CREATE TABLE a (
  a_id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE b (
  a_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES a (a_id)
, b_sequence INTEGER NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT pk_b PRIMARY KEY (a_id,b_sequence)
);

CREATE TABLE c (
  a_id INTEGER NOT NULL
, b_sequence INTEGER NOT NULL
, c_sequence INTEGER NOT NULL
, CONSTRAINT pk_c PRIMARY KEY (a_id,b_sequence,c_sequence)
, CONSTRAINT fk_c2b FOREIGN KEY(a_id,b_sequence)
    REFERENCES b(a_id,b_sequence)
);
```